# How to search in table using nested hstore column?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm new to PostgreSQL and recently I had contact to hstore, I'm looking for learn more about it.

This is my current situation:

I have a `people` table with a column `phones`, that is a hstore. One person can have multiple phones. The column seems like this:

```
"0"=>"{\"phone\":\"00000000000\",\"phone_type\":\"cell_phone\"}",
"1"=>"{\"phone\":\"11111111111\",\"phone_type\":\"cell_phone\"}", "__TYPE__"=>"__ARRAY__"
```

How could I make a query to find a person along the table with specific number?

I tried something like this, but it only allows me to search in the first item of hstore

```
SELECT
  "people".*
FROM
  "people"
WHERE
  "people"."organization_id" = 1
  AND ( NULLIF( regexp_replace( people.phones -> '0' , '[^0-9]*', '', 'g'), '') ilike '%00000000000%' )
```

Comment: Unrelated, but nowadays `jsonb` is probably more useful/flexible than `hstore`. But the correct solution is to use  a properly normalized data model with a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: We used the proper solution, that you suggested, to another case familiar to this one, but now in this case wont be possible. At least, not too early :/

 Anyway, its good to know that jsonb exists. Thank you.